# How can I use the std::fmt library with a C style format string?

Tags: string, templates, c++17, compile-time, fmt

I am trying to integrate the following logger library into my project.
https://github.com/MengRao/fmtlog

Since this library uses the fmt library in the background, it uses curly braces within the formatting string.

I make log calls through functional macros as follows.

```
#define LOG(format,...)
```

The usage of this macro is as follows;

```
LOG("test log message %d, %s", 10, "test1");
```

I did this because the old logger was used in this way in the current code base and there are too many LOG lines.

I want to do it using C style format specifiers while using the format library. I can do this at runtime, but I want to do it at compile time. Actually, what I want to do is to replace the format specifiers such as %d %s in the message I gave while using the LOG macro, with {} at compile time.

In summary, I mean

```
"test log message %d, %s"
```

How can I generate the following expression at compile time using a given string literal as above?

```
"test log message {}, {}"
```

How do you think I can do this?

Comment: The C++ standard library does not have such functionality. The original [fmt library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) (of which the standard is based on) have a [`printf`](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#printf-formatting) function. With that said, it might be better to "bit the bullet" and refactor the code to be future-proof with the native C++ formatting.

Comment: Hi, the best solution you said yes, but as I said, do you think I can make a tricky solution? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/hr76PvYod
I can think of such a solution. I am limiting its use. For example, a usage such as %4.f or %2d will not be valid in this way. @Someprogrammerdude